# Problema ao tentar pegar valor de um array

Tags: php, array

Estou tentando trabalhar com um array que recebo por POST, mas não estou conseguindo pegar os valores contido dentro do array.

Quando dou `print_r($_POST)` obtenho:

> Array ( [acesso] => Array ( ['KMEntrada'] => 1000 ['HorarioSaida'] =>
>   2017-06-16 14:20:58 ['Status'] => 0 ) )

Já tentei acessar usando `$_POST["acesso"]["KMEntrada"]` mas obtenho a seguinte mensagem de erro:

> Undefined index: KMEntrada

Comment: `echo $var['acesso']['KMEntrada']` isso?

Comment: Eu já tinha tentado assim, mas não funciona.

Comment: Aparece algum erro?

Comment: Undefined index: KMEntrada

Comment: Isso dentro de um for? pelo jeito o array do seu código está diferente do array da pergunta.

Comment: Eu pego esse array do código ` print_r($_POST);`

Comment: Usando o código que tu passou ficou assim `echo($_POST['acesso']['KMEntrada']);`

Comment: Agora deu certo... o código de tem ficar assim `echo($_POST['acesso']["'KMEntrada'"]);`

Answer (score 0):

Para retornar qualquer valor faça assim

```
$meuArray = array('acesso' => array('KMEntrada' => 1000, 'HorarioSaida' => '2017-06-16 14:20:58', 'Status' => 0));

echo $meuArray['acesso']['KMEntrada'] ."\n";

echo $meuArray['acesso']['HorarioSaida'] ."\n";

echo $meuArray['acesso']['Status'] ."\n";
```

[**exemplo - ideone**](https://ideone.com/395YXC)

Answer (score 0):

Para recuperar o valor, tive que inserir o seguinte código:

`$_POST['acesso']["'FrotaID'"]`

Comment: Isso não faz o menor sentido!!!

Comment: Tem como editar a pergunta e adicionar mais detalhes do seu problema? Assim como o Marcelo disse, a sua solução não faz sentido. O rray já havia te indicado a solução correta nos comentários e deu erro. Não ignore o erro. Se com a forma certa deu erro, tem coisa errada no seu código.

Answer (score 0):

Tenho **quase** certeza que o seu maior problema esta na [querystring](/questions/tagged/querystring), você esta passando ela, **muito provavelmente** desse modo:

```js
request = function() {
  $.ajax({
    url: "https://requestb.in/1fzmwxx1",
    type: "POST",
    data: {
      "acesso['KMEntrada']": 1000,
      "acesso['HorarioSaida']": '2017-06-16 14:20:58',
      "acesso['Status']": 0
    },
    success: function(returnjson) {},
    error: function(returnjson) {}
  });
}();
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Veja no [requestb.in](https://requestb.in/1fzmwxx1?inspect) como a informação chega:

> ## RAW BODY
>
> acesso%5B'KMEntrada'%5D=1000&acesso%5B'HorarioSaida'%5D=2017-06-16+14%3A20%3A58&acesso%5B'Status'%5D=0

Para enxergar melhor:

> ## RAW BODY URL ENCODED
>
> acesso['KMEntrada']=1000&acesso['HorarioSaida‌​']=2017-06-16 14:20:58&acesso['Status']=0

Quando na verdade bastava passar assim:

> ## RAW BODY
>
> acesso%5BKMEntrada%5D=1000&acesso%5BHorarioSaida%5D=2017-06-16+14%3A20%3A58&acesso%5BStatus%5D=0
>
> ## RAW BODY URL ENCODED
>
> acesso[KMEntrada]=1000&acesso[HorarioSaida]=2‌​017-06-16 14:20:58&acesso[Status]=0

O que você fez para acessar as variáveis dentro do array `$_POST['acesso']["'FrotaID'"]` funciona como um remendo, uma gambiarra, e não como uma solução definitiva, não é o recomendável...

## Porque não seria recomendável?

Se no backend você, ou algum outro desenvolvedor por acaso tentar converter o `$_POST` para um objeto, você não conseguira acessar as variáveis dentro da variável `acesso`, veja um exemplo do que quero dizer:

```
$_POST["acesso"] = (object) Array( "'KMEntrada'" => 1000, "'HorarioSaida'" => '2017-06-16 14:20:58', "'Status'" => 0, "teste" => 540 );
$teste = (object) $_POST; // casting da variável
echo $teste ->acesso->teste // Imprime 540
echo $teste ->acesso->'KMEntrada' // invalido
```

Se por acaso você tentar acessar o json usando javascript, também terá um erro de sintaxe:

```
$arr = array(
    "acesso" => array(
        "'KMEntrada'" => 1000,
        "'HorarioSaida'" => "2017-06-16 14:20:58",
        "'Status'" => 0
    )
);
$v = json_encode($arr);
echo "<script>";
echo "var a = ".$v.";";
echo "console.log(a.acesso);";
echo "console.log(a.acesso.'KMEntrada');";
echo "</script>";
```

Alem do que, não vejo algum motivo cabível para se passar uma variável com caracteres especiais, caso essa afirmação esteja incorreta, inclusive peço que me retifiquem:

> **Não existe algum contexto onde é valido definir uma variável em uma
>   queryString com caracteres especiais tipo aspas, arroba, cifrão e etc, isso inclusive poderia trazer problemas na hora de recuperar as variáveis passadas no backend**.

---

Basta saber como você esta enviando esse array pro seu backend e fazer a correção la, se for por ajax por exemplo:

```js
request = function() {
  $.ajax({
    url: "https://requestb.in/1fzmwxx1",
    type: "POST",
    data: {
      "acesso[KMEntrada]": 1000,
      "acesso[HorarioSaida]": '2017-06-16 14:20:58',
      "acesso[Status]": 0
    },
    success: function(returnjson) {},
    error: function(returnjson) {}
  });
}();
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Veja no [requestb.in](https://requestb.in/1fzmwxx1?inspect) a informação que chega:

> ## FORM/POST PARAMETERS
>
> acesso[HorarioSaida]: 2017-06-16 14:20:58
>
> acesso[Status]: 0
>
> acesso[KMEntrada]: 1000
>
> ## RAW BODY
>
> acesso%5BKMEntrada%5D=1000&acesso%5BHorarioSaida%5D=2017-06-16+14%3A20%3A58&acesso%5BStatus%5D=0

Deste modo, ai sim você pode facilmente acessar as variáveis do modo correto, que seria `$_POST['acesso']['KMEntrada']`